# Android Studio thinks interface is class after rename

Tags: java, android-studio

In my Java project in Android Studio (Hedgehog 2023.1.1), I had this interface declared:

```java
public interface Fetcher {
    ...
}
```

I later renamed it to `Manifest` using **Refactor**.  Everything worked fine afterward.  My app built and ran successfully.  However, Android Studio is highlighting places where I implement the interface saying, "Interface expected here":

```java
public class SomeImplementation implements Manifest {
    ...
}
```

When I hover over `Manifest`, the IDE identifies it as `public final class com.example.MyApp.Manifest`.  When I click on **Go To -> Type Declaration**, nothing pops up.

I've tried cleaning the build and restarting the IDE but the issue persists.  Like I said, my app builds and runs just fine.  How can I get Android Studio to realize that it really is an interface?

Comment: I already had this issue once, restarting the IDE by "invalidate cache and restart" did solve the issue. However, on the question of why this happened I have no idea.

Comment: Weird.  When I do that, it works briefly upon restart.  That is, it shows `Manifest` as an interface.  However, after a few seconds, it goes back to showing it as a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Android Studio got confused because the class `Manifest` already exists as `android.Manifest`.

Renaming the interface to something like `MyManifest` fixed the issue.